# How to Compare Object Values In Handlebar?

Tags: handlebars.js

This is my array of objects:

```
paper: [
  {
    "commentDate": "17-05-2023",
    "id": 1,
    "user_name": "xyz",
    "user_email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "user_rating": 4,
    "user_review": "woow",
    "commentTime": "11:03:51",
    "paperId": 2,
    "userId": 3
  },
  {
    "commentDate": "17-05-2023",
    "id": 3,
    "user_name": "pqr",
    "user_email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "user_rating": 5,
    "user_review": "very nice!",
    "commentTime": "11:17:57",
    "paperId": 2,
    "userId": 4
  }
]
```

In my handlebars page, I want to print data such as:

```
{{#each paper}}
     {{user_name}}
      {{user_email}
    
              
{{/each}}
```

Now I want to perform some if else logic under each block like below:

```
{{#each paper}}
     {{user_name}}
      {{user_email}
      

        if (user_rating == 4 ){
         } else if(user_rating == 3) {
         }else{
         }

              
{{/each}}
```

How can I do this? Please help me out.

This my helper:

```
'math': function(v1, v2,options){
      if(v1 == v2){
        return options.fn(this);
      }
      else{
        return options.inverse(this);
      }
    }
```

And I tried the following:

```
   {{#each paper}}
         {{user_name}}
          {{user_email}
          {{#math user_rating 5}}
          //some logic
           {{else}}{{#math user_rating 4}}
             //some logic
            {{else}}
                //some logic
              {{/math}} 
                  
    {{/each}}
```

And it says, "math does not match with each".

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing your second `#math` block with a corresponding `{{/math}}`. However, even if you were, you would probably not get the output you expect because nothing would ever get to the second `else` branch because it would get handled by the `else` branch before it. What you want to do is to use `else` *with* the `math` helper, as in `{{else math user_rating 4}}`.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  {{#each paper}}
    {{user_name}}
    {{user_email}}
    {{#math user_rating 5}}
      <p>User Rating is 5!</p>
    {{else math user_rating 4}}
      <p>User rating is 4</p>   
    {{else}}
      <p>User rating is less than 4</p>
    {{/math}}
  {{/each}}
`);

Handlebars.registerHelper('math', function(v1, v2,options) {
  if (v1 == v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});

const data = {
  paper: [
    {
      user_name: "xyz",
      user_email: "abc@gmail.com",
      user_rating: 4
    },
    {
      user_name: "pqr",
      user_email: "xyz@gmail.com",
      user_rating: 5,
    }
  ]
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the values will come from a route after a query using sequelize. How will I achieve that?

Comment: @Shabnam: The source of the data has no effect on how the helper is used.

Comment: @Shabnam: Please indicate whether this post was able to help you.